Azure CLI Policy Definition Error: 'Could not find member 'mode' on object of type 'PolicyRuleDefinition''
I am trying to create a custom policy in Azure using Azure CLI, but I keep encountering an error related to parsing the policy JSON file. Here are the details:
Command:
az policy definition create --name "deny-public-ip" --display-name "Deny Public IP" --description "Deny creation of public IP addresses" --rules "policy-rules.json" --mode "All"

Error Message:
(InvalidPolicyRule) Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'mode' on object of type 'PolicyRuleDefinition'. Path 'mode'.'
Code: InvalidPolicyRule
Message: Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'mode' on object of type 'PolicyRuleDefinition'. Path 'mode'.'.

Checked the JSON File: I verified the JSON content multiple times to ensure it follows Azure's policy structure.
Encoding: Confirmed the file is in UTF-8 format.
Editing and Resaving: Edited the file using nano in Azure Cloud Shell and resaved it.
JSON Content:
Here is the content of my policy-rules.json file:
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }
}

Screenshot:

I've also tried running CLI as admin and adding the subscription to my Tenant..
Any insights or guidance on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Looking at the documentation, your json file should only contain the policy rule:
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}

And you can use the cli command the same way you're already doing it:
az policy definition create --name "deny-public-ip" --display-name "Deny Public IP" --description "Deny creation of public IP addresses" --rules "policy-rules.json" --mode "All"

